# Gracenote GNSDK compile on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, codeblocks, gracenote, intel-ipp

I want to compile an application with GNSDK (Gracenote SDK) on linux but I have errors (I use Code::Blocks). I wan't to use gracenote fingerprint with musicid_file_trackid function.

My compilation with Visual Studio on Windows work fine but not on Linux (Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Compiler).

I have this issues :

```
||=== Build: Release in Gracenote (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
gcsl_fingerprint.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »|
gn_patchfp.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »|
CMFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
CMFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32f »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdFree_32f »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdInitAlloc_32f »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdInitAlloc_32f »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdGetBufSize_32f »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_8u »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdGetBufSize_32f »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_8u »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwd_32f_I »|
CMFrameManager.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwd_32f_I »|
CMHistogramEqualizer.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMinMax_32f »|
CMHistogramEqualizer.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMinMax_32f »|
CMHistogramEqualizer.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsSubC_32f_I »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTInitAlloc_R_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFree_R_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTGetBufSize_R_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_8u »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsAbs_32s_I »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFree_R_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMaxAbs_32s »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsLShiftC_32s_I »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsRShiftC_32s_I »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMul_32s_ISfs »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFwd_RToPerm_32s_Sfs »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMagSquared_32sc32s_Sfs »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs »|
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32f »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »|
GNDSP_Resampler.c|| référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »|
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(GNDSP_Resampler.o):GNDSP_Resampler.c|| encore plus de références indéfinies suivent vers « ippsDotProd_32f »|
gcsl_memory_markers.c|| référence indéfinie vers « pthread_key_create »|
gcsl_memory_markers.c|| référence indéfinie vers « pthread_key_delete »|
gcsl_memory_markers.c|| référence indéfinie vers « pthread_getspecific »|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|

Linker commaandline:

    g++ -Llib -Llib_static -o bin/Release/Gracenote obj/Release/main.o  -s -pthread  lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a lib_static/libgnsdk_link.a lib_static/libgnsdk_lookup_local.a lib_static/libgnsdk_lookup_localstream.a lib_static/libgnsdk_manager.a lib_static/libgnsdk_moodgrid.a lib_static/libgnsdk_musicid.a lib_static/libgnsdk_musicid_file.a lib_static/libgnsdk_musicid_stream.a lib_static/libgnsdk_playlist.a lib_static/libgnsdk_storage_sqlite.a lib_static/libgnsdk_video.a 


-------------- Build: Release in Gracenote (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Llib -Llib_static -o bin/Release/Gracenote obj/Release/main.o  -s -pthread  lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a lib_static/libgnsdk_link.a lib_static/libgnsdk_lookup_local.a lib_static/libgnsdk_lookup_localstream.a lib_static/libgnsdk_manager.a lib_static/libgnsdk_moodgrid.a lib_static/libgnsdk_musicid.a lib_static/libgnsdk_musicid_file.a lib_static/libgnsdk_musicid_stream.a lib_static/libgnsdk_playlist.a lib_static/libgnsdk_storage_sqlite.a lib_static/libgnsdk_video.a
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(gcsl_fingerprint.o): dans la fonction « _fingerprint_init_func »:
gcsl_fingerprint.c:(.text+0xa1): référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(gn_patchfp.o): dans la fonction « patchfp_initialize »:
gn_patchfp.c:(.text+0x5): référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « CMFP_Destroy »:
CMFingerprinter.c:(.text+0xc2): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « CMFP_Create »:
CMFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x285): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32f »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFrameManager.o): dans la fonction « CMFM_Destroy »:
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x211): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdFree_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x231): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFrameManager.o): dans la fonction « CMFM_Create »:
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x34d): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdInitAlloc_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x461): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdInitAlloc_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x4af): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdGetBufSize_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x4bf): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_8u »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x4d9): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdGetBufSize_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x4e5): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_8u »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFrameManager.o): dans la fonction « CMFM_AppendDualPCMData »:
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0xe38): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwd_32f_I »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0xf53): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwd_32f_I »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMHistogramEqualizer.o): dans la fonction « hist_eq_dual »:
CMHistogramEqualizer.c:(.text+0x152): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMinMax_32f »
CMHistogramEqualizer.c:(.text+0x169): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMinMax_32f »
CMHistogramEqualizer.c:(.text+0x2b4): référence indéfinie vers « ippsSubC_32f_I »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « FixedFAPIFingerprinterCreate »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x2fb): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x30f): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x34e): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTInitAlloc_R_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x3af): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFree_R_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x3d6): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x3e2): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x4a7): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTGetBufSize_R_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x4ba): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_8u »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x59e): référence indéfinie vers « ippsAbs_32s_I »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x5a8): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « FixedFAPIFingerprinterDelete »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x67c): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFree_R_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x697): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x6a4): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x6d1): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « ScaleToMaxQ »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x96d): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMaxAbs_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x9e0): référence indéfinie vers « ippsLShiftC_32s_I »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x9fc): référence indéfinie vers « ippsRShiftC_32s_I »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « ExtractSoftSubFingerprint »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0xad9): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMul_32s_ISfs »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0xb18): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFwd_RToPerm_32s_Sfs »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0xb6b): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMagSquared_32sc32s_Sfs »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « ApplyLowPassFilter »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x161c): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « ApplyLowPassHQ »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x166c): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(GNDSP_Resampler.o): dans la fonction « GNDSP_DestroyResampler »:
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0x41): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFree »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(GNDSP_Resampler.o): dans la fonction « GNDSP_CreateResampler »:
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0x539): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMalloc_32f »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(GNDSP_Resampler.o): dans la fonction « GNDSP_Resample »:
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0xa39): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0xa51): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0xa69): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0xa85): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »
GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0xacf): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDotProd_32f »
lib_static/libgnsdk_dsp.a(GNDSP_Resampler.o):GNDSP_Resampler.c:(.text+0xb31): encore plus de références indéfinies suivent vers « ippsDotProd_32f »
lib_static/libgnsdk_manager.a(gcsl_process.o): dans la fonction « gcsl_process_library_sym »:
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x49): référence indéfinie vers « dlsym »
lib_static/libgnsdk_manager.a(gcsl_process.o): dans la fonction « gcsl_process_library_load »:
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x262): référence indéfinie vers « dlopen »
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x366): référence indéfinie vers « dlclose »
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

How can I resolved this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Vincent LEVEQUE

Edit : 
I have tried your recommandation but with this linker options :

```
-lgnsdk_dsp
-lgnsdk_link
-lgnsdk_lookup_local
-lgnsdk_lookup_localstream
-lgnsdk_manager
-lgnsdk_moodgrid
-lgnsdk_musicid
-lgnsdk_musicid_file
-lgnsdk_musicid_stream
-lgnsdk_playlist
-lgnsdk_storage_sqlite
-lgnsdk_video
-lippcore
-lippcc
-lippch
-lippcv
-lippdc
-lippi
-lipps
-lippvm
-pthread
```

But I have always errors :

```
-------------- Clean: Release in Gracenote (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "Gracenote - Release"

-------------- Build: Release in Gracenote (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

gcc -Wall -O2  -c /home/membre/codeblocks/Gracenote/main.c -o obj/Release/main.o
g++ -Llib/linux_x86-64 -Llib_static/linux_x86-64 -Lipps -o bin/Release/Gracenote obj/Release/main.o  -s -lgnsdk_dsp -lgnsdk_link -lgnsdk_lookup_local -lgnsdk_lookup_localstream -lgnsdk_manager -lgnsdk_moodgrid -lgnsdk_musicid -lgnsdk_musicid_file -lgnsdk_musicid_stream -lgnsdk_playlist -lgnsdk_storage_sqlite -lgnsdk_video -lippcore -lippcc -lippch -lippcv -lippdc -lippi -lipps -lippvm -pthread  
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(gcsl_fingerprint.o): dans la fonction « _fingerprint_init_func »:
gcsl_fingerprint.c:(.text+0xa1): référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(gn_patchfp.o): dans la fonction « patchfp_initialize »:
gn_patchfp.c:(.text+0x5): référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFrameManager.o): dans la fonction « CMFM_Destroy »:
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x211): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdFree_32f »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(CMFrameManager.o): dans la fonction « CMFM_Create »:
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x34d): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdInitAlloc_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x461): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdInitAlloc_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x4af): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdGetBufSize_32f »
CMFrameManager.c:(.text+0x4d9): référence indéfinie vers « ippsDCTFwdGetBufSize_32f »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « FixedFAPIFingerprinterCreate »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x34e): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTInitAlloc_R_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x3af): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFree_R_32s »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x4a7): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTGetBufSize_R_32s »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « FixedFAPIFingerprinterDelete »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0x67c): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFree_R_32s »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_dsp.a(FixedFAPIFingerprinter.o): dans la fonction « ExtractSoftSubFingerprint »:
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0xb18): référence indéfinie vers « ippsFFTFwd_RToPerm_32s_Sfs »
FixedFAPIFingerprinter.c:(.text+0xb6b): référence indéfinie vers « ippsMagSquared_32sc32s_Sfs »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_manager.a(gcsl_process.o): dans la fonction « gcsl_process_library_sym »:
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x49): référence indéfinie vers « dlsym »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_manager.a(gcsl_process.o): dans la fonction « gcsl_process_library_load »:
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x262): référence indéfinie vers « dlopen »
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x366): référence indéfinie vers « dlclose »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_manager.a(gcsl_process.o): dans la fonction « gcsl_process_library_free »:
gcsl_process.c:(.text+0x411): référence indéfinie vers « dlclose »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_musicid_stream.a(gnsdk_musicid_stream.o): dans la fonction « gnsdk_musicidstream_channel_audio_write »:
gnsdk_musicid_stream.c:(.text+0x2982): référence indéfinie vers « gcsl_circbuf_write »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_musicid_stream.a(mids_fsm.o): dans la fonction « mids_fsm_state_process_circularbuffer »:
mids_fsm.c:(.text+0x1043): référence indéfinie vers « gcsl_circbuf_size »
mids_fsm.c:(.text+0x10ec): référence indéfinie vers « gcsl_circbuf_get_newest »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_musicid_stream.a(mids_internal.o): dans la fonction « audio_session_delete »:
mids_internal.c:(.text+0x527): référence indéfinie vers « gcsl_circbuf_delete »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_musicid_stream.a(mids_internal.o): dans la fonction « audio_session_create »:
mids_internal.c:(.text+0x8ed): référence indéfinie vers « gcsl_circbuf_create »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_storage_sqlite.a(sqlite3.o): dans la fonction « unixDlSym »:
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4606): référence indéfinie vers « dlsym »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_storage_sqlite.a(sqlite3.o): dans la fonction « unixDlError »:
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x1e4f9): référence indéfinie vers « dlerror »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_storage_sqlite.a(sqlite3.o): dans la fonction « unixDlOpen »:
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x45f9): référence indéfinie vers « dlopen »
lib_static/linux_x86-64/libgnsdk_storage_sqlite.a(sqlite3.o): dans la fonction « unixDlClose »:
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x4614): référence indéfinie vers « dlclose »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsAbs_32s_I_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsAbs_32s_I_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsAbs_32s_I_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsAbs_32s_I »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsAbs_32s_I_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsDCTFwd_32f_I_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsDCTFwd_32f_I_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsDCTFwd_32f_I_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsDCTFwd_32f_I »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsDCTFwd_32f_I_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsDotProd_16s32s32s_Sfs_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsDotProd_32f_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsDotProd_32f_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsDotProd_32f_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsDotProd_32f »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsDotProd_32f_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsFree_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsFree_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsFree_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsFree »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsFree_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsLShiftC_32s_I_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsLShiftC_32s_I_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsLShiftC_32s_I_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsLShiftC_32s_I »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsLShiftC_32s_I_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMalloc_32f_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMalloc_32f_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMalloc_32f_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsMalloc_32f »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMalloc_32f_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMalloc_32s_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMalloc_32s_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMalloc_32s_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsMalloc_32s »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMalloc_32s_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMalloc_8u_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMalloc_8u_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMalloc_8u_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsMalloc_8u »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMalloc_8u_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMaxAbs_32s_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMaxAbs_32s_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMaxAbs_32s_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsMaxAbs_32s »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMaxAbs_32s_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMinMax_32f_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMinMax_32f_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMinMax_32f_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsMinMax_32f »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMinMax_32f_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMul_32s_ISfs_as.o): dans la fonction « aucun symbole »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMul_32s_ISfs_as.s:(.text+0x1): référence indéfinie vers « ippSafeInit »
ipps/libipps.a(jmp_ippsMul_32s_ISfs_as.o): dans la fonction « ippsMul_32s_ISfs »:
/localdisk/commander/production/ipp901gold/linux_intel64/.build/linux/obj/intel64/ipps/emerged_compl/nonpic/dispatcher/jmp_ippsMul_32s_ISfs_as.s:(.text+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs »
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Comment: You are not linking the required Intel Integrated Performance Primitives
libraries. It's impossible to tell why unless you post the the gcc linkage
command that generates the errors. You will find it in the **Build log**
tab (not the **Build messages** tab) of the failing build. You are also
not linking `libpthread`, probably because you have not added `-pthread` to **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**.

Comment: How can I linking Intel Integrated Performance Primitives libraries ? It's possible on LInux ?

Comment: As I said, it's impossible to explain the failure more precisely without
seeing the failing gcc linkage command from the build log. Post this
information in the question (not in comments).

Comment: Have you any idea how I can solve my problem with the Build Log ? Thank you

Comment: Could you please try changing order of IPP libraries in linking command? I.e. put ippcore as the last one, etc.

Comment: I tried but I still have errors..

Comment: We see the error "référence indéfinie vers « ippStaticInit »"  but apparently the function was deprecated : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ipp-dispatcher-control-functions-ippinit-functions

Does it can be a reason for the problem ? How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gracenote SDK libraries that you are linking make calls to functions
that are defined in some or other of the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives libraries.
The Gracenote SDK (at least the one you have got) evidently expects you to have those
libraries. Perhaps they are contained somewhere in the SDK. Perhaps you are supposed to
get them yourself. Anyhow, you are not linking any of them; hence the undefined reference
linkage errors.

These libraries have names of the form `libipp*.a`. Look for them in your SDK. If you
can't find them, you can download them free from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/free_ipp)

Once you have got them, you will need to link your program with a commandline like:

```
g++ -L/path/to/lib -L/path/to/lib_static -L/path/to/the/IPP/libraries \ 
-o bin/Release/Gracenote obj/Release/main.o  \
-lgnsdk_dsp \
-lgnsdk_link \
-lgnsdk_lookup_local \ 
-lgnsdk_lookup_localstream \ 
-lgnsdk_manager \
-lgnsdk_moodgrid \
-lgnsdk_musicid \
-lgnsdk_musicid_file \ 
-lgnsdk_musicid_stream \ 
-lgnsdk_playlist \
-lgnsdk_storage_sqlite \ 
-lgnsdk_video \
-lipp? \
-lipp?? \
-lipp??? \
-pthread
```

where `-lipp? -lipp?? -lipp???` are whatever IPP libraries are needed to
resolve all the references in the SDK libraries.

You need to configure the options in your Code::Blocks project so that it
will generate the correct linkage commandline for g++. Do this as follows:

In  -> **Build options** -> **Search directories** -> **Linker**, add each of:

```
/path/to/lib 
/path/to/lib_static 
/path/to/the/IPP/libraries
```

In  -> **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Link libraries**,
remove all the `lib_static/libgnsdk???.a` options you have entered there.

In  -> **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**,
add all of the `-l<name>` options that I've listed above, plus `-pthread`, in the order
that I've listed them. (Note that `-l<name>` is correct; `-llib<name>` is wrong.)

You can experiment to discover exactly which IPP libraries you need for a successul linkage.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I begin to understanding the link library system but I have always errors (edit my answer)..

Comment: @Vincentleveque I sorry, I can't solve this for you "at a distance". The linkage is very complex and very broken. You need the help of someone
who is experienced with the GNSDK on Linux as well as with GCC.
I am the second but not the first :(

Comment: I do my tests on an old computer with an AMD Athlon. Is it possible that my problem is related to the fact that this is not an Intel processor ?

I can try on a newer PC with a Intel Core i3